# DotNetOpenAuth template doesn't work when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I got the DotNetOpenAuth template (sample) working just fine on my computer locally (as localhost) but when i publish it to my server I get this error:

```
Error Summary
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
```

configuration data for the page is invalid.

And Detailed Error Information

```
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    Unknown
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x800700b7
Config Error    There is a duplicate 'uri' section defined
```

Web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
    </configSections>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
         which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name. 
         It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <uri>
        <idn enabled="All"/>
        <iriParsing enabled="true"/>
    </uri>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true"/>
        <settings>
            <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
            <servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>
        </settings>
    </system.net>
    <!-- this is an optional configuration section where aspects of dotnetopenauth can be customized -->
    <dotNetOpenAuth>
        <messaging>
            <untrustedWebRequest>
                <whitelistHosts>
                    <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
                </whitelistHosts>
            </untrustedWebRequest>
        </messaging>
        <openid>
            <relyingParty>
                <behaviors>
                    <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
                    <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth"/>
                </behaviors>
                <store type="RelyingPartyLogic.RelyingPartyApplicationDbStore, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
            </relyingParty>
        </openid>
        <oauth>
            <serviceProvider>
                <store type="RelyingPartyLogic.NonceDbStore, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
            </serviceProvider>
        </oauth>
        <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
        <reporting enabled="true"/>
    </dotNetOpenAuth>
    <!-- log4net is a 3rd party (free) logger library that DotNetOpenAuth will use if present but does not require. -->
    <log4net>
        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <bufferSize value="100"/>
            <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <commandText value="INSERT INTO [Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)"/>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
                <dbType value="DateTime"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@thread"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="255"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="50"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@logger"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="255"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@message"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="4000"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                    <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@exception"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="2000"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
            </parameter>
        </appender>
        <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default level -->
        <root>
            <level value="WARN"/>
            <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
        </root>
        <!-- Specify the level for some specific categories -->
        <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth">
            <level value="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId">
            <level value="INFO"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth">
            <level value="INFO"/>
        </logger>
    </log4net>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!-- Remember to keep this connection string in sync with the one (if any) that appears in the log4net section. -->
        <add name="DatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Pubba_V05.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <remove assembly="DotNetOpenAuth.Contracts"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" name="Pubba_V05"/>
        </authentication>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.
            -->
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="OAuthAuthenticationModule" type="RelyingPartyLogic.OAuthAuthenticationModule, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
            <add name="Database" type="RelyingPartyLogic.Database, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
        </httpModules>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="Database">
            <providers>
                <add name="Database" type="RelyingPartyLogic.DataRoleProvider, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="OAuthAuthenticationModule" type="RelyingPartyLogic.OAuthAuthenticationModule, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
            <add name="Database" type="RelyingPartyLogic.Database, RelyingPartyLogic"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="DataApiBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="OAuthAuthorizationManager, __code" principalPermissionMode="Custom"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <!--<service behaviorConfiguration="DataApiBehavior" name="DataApi">
            </service>-->
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <location path="default.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

How could i fix this?

Comment: If you post your web.config file, someone might be able to find the issue

Comment: Found these warnings: Message 1 Could not find schema information for the element 'dotNetOpenAuth'. C:\XXX\Web.config 33 3 Pubba V05
Message 2 Could not find schema information for the element 'messaging'. C:\XXX\Web.config 34 4 Pubba V05
Message 3 Could not find schema information for the element 'untrustedWebRequest'. C:\XXX\Web.config 35 5 Pubba V05

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was found here:

```
<section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

By deleting that row that error was solved.

This problem appears after upgrade to .NET 4.0, which moves a lot of configuration to machine.config.